# How to get the Cartesian product of this dictionary?

Tags: python

How do I get all possible permutations of this dictionary? For instance, if my dictionary is:

```
x = {'strategies': [{'Moving Average': [{'Moving Average': 'SMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1},
                                        {'Moving Average': 'EMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1},
                                        {'Moving Average': 'WMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1}]},
                    {'Shrek': [{'shrek1': 1, 'shrek2': 1, 'shrek3': 1, 'shrek4': 1}]}]}
```

I would like to have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
p = [
    {'strategies': {
        'Moving Average': {'Moving Average': 'SMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1},
        'Shrek': {'shrek1': 1, 'shrek2': 1, 'shrek3': 1, 'shrek4': 1}}
    },
    {'strategies': {
        'Moving Average': {'Moving Average': 'EMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1},
        'Shrek': {'shrek1': 1, 'shrek2': 1, 'shrek3': 1, 'shrek4': 1}}
    },
    {'strategies': {
        'Moving Average': {'Moving Average': 'WMA', 'Parameter': 'High', 'Initial': 1, 'Final': 1},
        'Shrek': {'shrek1': 1, 'shrek2': 1, 'shrek3': 1, 'shrek4': 1}}
    },
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using any of the combinatoric functions in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module? Or just writing some plain `for` loop? What was the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Why do you think he would need `itertools`?  It looks like OP is just trying to flatten the list of dictionaries.  How would you use `itertools` to solve the problem?

Comment: I just read "cartesian product" and suggested it. I'm not saying using itertools is required or a solution at all.